# XSLT select attributes from another node

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, key

This is my XML file :

```
<root>
    <headers>
        <header value="type1" />
        <header value="type3" />
        <header value="type2" />
    </headers>
    <data type1="data1_1" type2="data1_2" type3="data1_3" />
    <data type1="data2_1" type2="data2_2" type3="data2_3" />
</root>
```

And I want to generate CSV with only headers listed in headers section. This is my xslt file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="unicode" />
<xsl:template match="root">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="headers">
    <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="separator">
    <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- display first line header work ok -->
<xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:key name="mykey" match="header" use="@value" />

<!-- For each data parameters check if exist in header and display with the good order ! NOT WORK -->
<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:if test="key('mykey', name())">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want this output format (CSV):

```
type1 type3 type2
data1_1 data1_3 data1_2
data2_1 data2_3 data2_2
```

But my output is ( data type2 is not under correct header ):

```
type1 type3 type2
data1_1 data1_2 data1_3
data2_1 data2_2 data2_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes have no set order. Elements do. So let's use the elements to provide your ordering:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="unicode" />
<xsl:template match="Results">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="headers">
    <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="separator">
    <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- display first line header work ok -->
<xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Use the order of the headers to choose the order of the attributes. -->
<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/headers/header">
        <xsl:value-of select="$data/@*[name()=current()/@value]"/>        
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
    type1   
    type3   
    type2   


data1_1 data1_3 data1_2
data2_1 data2_3 data2_2
```

The headers are on separate lines because I didn't change that part of your code.

Comment: Thanks! the solution was to use variable and not key, I have try it but I did not find the condition that you use, many thanks

Comment: Take a look at the answer of @michael.hor257k on how to use variables. In larger xml trees it can be quite inefficient to navigate in such a tree using your approach

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I would do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="headers" select="headers/header" />
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="data">
        <xsl:variable name="data" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/@*[name()=current()/@value]"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively (and perhaps a bit more efficiently), you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="data-value" match="data/@*" use="concat(name(), '|', generate-id(..))" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="headers" select="headers/header" />
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="data">
        <xsl:variable name="data-id" select="generate-id()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('data-value', concat(@value, '|', $data-id))"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

BTW, the result is a tab-separated file, not CSV.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I'm French and never use real Comma Separated Value, because some people use coma as decimal separator, and xls, pandas and many other can parse TSV without problem.

Comment: That's fine, except that that calling it CSV is rather confusing. BTW, this (the 1st version) does basically the same thing as the accepted answer, only simpler.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a template for text() nodes to get rid of all the text between elements (new lines, indents)
2. Put new lines between rows explicitly

Here is your xslt with minor fixes that does what you want:

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="unicode" />
    
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
            
    <xsl:template match="headers">
        <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="separator">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- display first line header work ok -->
    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:key name="mykey" match="header" use="@value" />
    
    <!-- For each data parameters check if exist in header and display with the good order ! NOT WORK -->
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:if test="key('mykey', name())">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:call-template name="separator" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```